# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) ubuntu

Tags: firefox, selenium

I had working selenium with my firefox, but today morning when i ran my test i got the same error. I updated selenium-webdriver for current version ( 2.38 ), but i still have that error.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
# /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@taxand/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:79:in `connect_until_stable'
```

also

i checked it in my other project where i have 2.35 version and it also worked yesterday - and there it also doesn't work today ;o

So i suppose that is no selenium issue, but my FF can be broken? But i also tried to run it with custom firefox_path to older firefox versions, and the issue is the same :<

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've found the same problem in Mac OS X Mavericks after I updated the Firefox 26.

I solved the problem by updating the selenium-webdriver gem

In your gemfile, replace your current selenium-webdriver gem line with

`gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.38.0"`

In your console, `gem update selenium-webdriver`.

Then `bundle install`.

Try the running the test after.

Comment: Thanks @Dmtri -- that worked for me. Did you also notice that you lost the ability to scroll on Chrome after selenium-webdriver failed to connect on Firefox? Super weird.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't used it with Chrome before.

Comment: This also worked for me on Windows. Thanks @dmtri.com

Comment: I still occasionally get the error even with 2.38.0.

Comment: check the release notes for which FF versions a particular selenium-webdriver gem version supports: The latest 2.43.0 added support up to FF 32  -- https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES

Comment: I got this error when using selenium-webdriver 2.42.0 and FF 32. Updating to selenium-webdriver 2.43.0 resolved the issue for me.